# RSpec should have_link fails despite link existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a RSpec test that keeps failing.

```
subject { page }
visit user_path(user)
it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
```

But when I load the page myself I can see that the link is working well. Any ideas ? No spelling mistake as well.

Possible to see the page that RSpec loaded in the test?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `visit user_path(user)` isn't executing in the right context.

Try either:

```
subject { page }
it do
  visit user_path(user) 
  should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user))
end
```

Or:

```
subject { page }
before { visit user_path(user) }
it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
```

If you would like to see the html, you can use a `save_and_open_page` statement.