# Use capybara to select a delete destroy link on page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, capybara, destroy

So I need to use capybara for testing to find a deletion button on a page. The following is where the delete button is nested:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/contacts/7" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

I was trying something like:

```
expect(page).to have_css('Destroy')
```

Comment: There were similar questions [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865625/capybara-matcher-for-presence-of-button-or-link) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424776/rspec-should-have-link-fails-despite-link-existence)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I might have solved it another way: I used     page.has_selector?('Destroy'), which is essentially finding the Destroy link without having to go through all of the css/html. Thanks https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara